# Will the list delete its values after the session is done?

Tags: python, list, append

I'm trying to append some answers to a list, and that works. But what happens when the session is over? Will that be deleted from the list?
The issue is, when I run the code again, looks like the list is empty.
Any suggestions on how to avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the session"?

Comment: *"the code"* - What code? You haven't shown any.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am assuming that by session your mean the program...that said, one way, more simple one, would be to pass the data to a file and read it back when your program initializes again:

```
#import json
your_list = [# your data here...]

# open file in write mode
with open(r'your/path/here', 'w') as fp:
    for item in your_list:
        # write each item on a new line
        fp.write(f"{item}\n")
    #json.dump(your_list,fp)

#then when your program starts...

with open(r'your/path/here', 'r') as fp:
    your_list.extend(fp.read().splitlines())
    #your_list = json.load(fp)
```

Of course you could create a database but this is just quick and dirty since no other requesits where specified in the question.Like mentioned juanpa for best practices you could use `json` but again as i said in the answer this was just quick and dirty...

Comment: you really should probably just use JSON or equivalent existing standard formats, and avoid having people cook up their own formats like this. Best to learn good practices early.

Comment: thank you for the heads up , but again there are many ways and this was just quick and dirty as I myself pointed out...but thanks for upgrading my answer